# how do compiler differentiate between int and char pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-optimization

I have a `int` pointer and a `char` pointer.

I know that pointer just stores a memory address. Now if I have an `int` pointer my address gets incremented by 4 bytes when I request the next value.

Now where in compiler or memory do we store the instructions that an `int` pointer must be incremented by 4 bytes and a `char` pointer must be incremented by 1 byte when we request for a next value?

Comment: The compiler remembers the type of the pointer, and generates the appropriate machine instructions. It uses internal structures to record the type, the identifier, and whether a variable has been initialised, or used, so it can issue warnings. These do not form part of the generated code.

Comment: int and char, etc are a notion of the high level language.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: When I go to cut a piece of wood that is two feet long, I remember that I want it to be two feet long and mark and cut it as such.  Neither the saw nor the wood are aware of this, that information only exists in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The operation that is performed is determined by the types of its operands.

Consider a “plus” operation with two operands, `p + n`. If the type of `p` is “pointer to `int`” and the type of `n` is `int`, the compiler generates instructions to compute the address that is `n` times `sizeof(int)` bytes beyond where `p` points. If the type of `p` is “pointer to `char`” and the type of `n` is `int`, the compiler generates instructions to compute the address that is `n` times `sizeof(char)` bytes beyond where `p` points.

Similarly, in the expression `*p`, if the type of `p` is “pointer to `int`”, the compiler generates an instruction to load a four-byte integer from memory. If the type of `p` is “pointer to `char`”, the compiler generates an instruction to load a one-byte integer from memory.

For subscript operations, `p[n]` is defined to be *((p) + (n))`, so it is a combination of the above two operations.

(Note that the above applies to simple compilation of isolated expressions. Overall, compilers may optimize programs, so the resulting assembly may be different from what is described above, but it will have the same effects.)

Answer (score 0):

The increment is stored in the assembly code. You may see something that is either eax+4 or 3[eax] (btw these two are not the same). Essentially the assembly code is telling the computer during run time how to increment.

How does the compiler know to do this? Well that’s from the code that makes the compiler. It creates what’s called an abstract system tree or a more usefully a graph. These graphs can ensure that rules are followed, like the increment.

If you’re interested in this read a book on compilers as well as computer architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it.

```
int fun1 ( int *x )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    int sa;
    
    sa=0;
    for(ra=0;ra<100;ra++)
    {
        sa+=x[ra];
    }
    return(sa);
}
char fun2 ( char *x )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    char sa;
    
    sa=0;
    for(ra=0;ra<100;ra++)
    {
        sa+=x[ra];
    }
    return(sa);
}
char fun3 ( short *x )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    short sa;
    
    sa=0;
    for(ra=0;ra<100;ra++)
    {
        sa+=x[ra];
    }
    return(sa);
}
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
   4:   e2403004    sub r3, r0, #4
   8:   e2800f63    add r0, r0, #396    ; 0x18c
   c:   e5b31004    ldr r1, [r3, #4]!
  10:   e1530000    cmp r3, r0
  14:   e0822001    add r2, r2, r1
  18:   1afffffb    bne c <fun1+0xc>
  1c:   e1a00002    mov r0, r2
  20:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000024 <fun2>:
  24:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
  28:   e2402001    sub r2, r0, #1
  2c:   e2801063    add r1, r0, #99 ; 0x63
  30:   e5f20001    ldrb    r0, [r2, #1]!
  34:   e0833000    add r3, r3, r0
  38:   e1520001    cmp r2, r1
  3c:   e20330ff    and r3, r3, #255    ; 0xff
  40:   1afffffa    bne 30 <fun2+0xc>
  44:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  48:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000004c <fun3>:
  4c:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
  50:   e2402002    sub r2, r0, #2
  54:   e280c0c6    add r12, r0, #198   ; 0xc6
  58:   e1f210b2    ldrh    r1, [r2, #2]!
  5c:   e0813003    add r3, r1, r3
  60:   e1a00803    lsl r0, r3, #16
  64:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
  68:   e152000c    cmp r2, r12
  6c:   e1a00820    lsr r0, r0, #16
  70:   e1a03843    asr r3, r3, #16
  74:   1afffff7    bne 58 <fun3+0xc>
  78:   e20000ff    and r0, r0, #255    ; 0xff
  7c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

And you clearly see:

```
   c:   e5b31004    ldr r1, [r3, #4]!

  30:   e5f20001    ldrb    r0, [r2, #1]!

  58:   e1f210b2    ldrh    r1, [r2, #2]!
```

You can see the handling of the halfword and byte operations as well (this architecture uses 32 bit registers).